# Finding a subarray that equals the given sum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to write code for a program that returns an array that contains the starting and ending position of subarray whose sum of elements is equal to the given sum. The code only works in case subarray starts from position 1, but not in case if required subarray starts from any other position.

Here's the code :

```
class Solution:
    def subArraySum(self,arr, n, s): 
       for i in range(0,n-1):
           sum=0
           for j in range(i,n):
               sum=sum+arr[j]
               if sum==s:
                   a=[i+1,j+1]
                   break
               else:
                   a=[-1]
           if len(a)==2:
               return a
```

Comment: That's because you start the sum from the first element and don't look at the sums starting at a different index.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
for j in range(i,n):
```

must change to this:

```
for j in range(i,i+n):
```

because you need to loop through the subArray of length n

Comment: How can you assume what `n` is?